# How do I properly use macro conditionals in header-only libraries?

Tags: c++, linker, macros

Assume the following code:

```cpp
/******* mylib.h *******/
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
public:
    void test()
    {
#ifdef MYDEF
      ::std::cout<<"ZERO\n";
#else
      ::std::cout<<"ONE\n";
#endif
    }
};


/******* module.h *******/
#include "mylib.h"

class module
{
public:
    void test();
}


/******* module.cpp *******/
#include "module.h"

class module
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        foo foo_;
        foo_.test();
    }
};


/******* main.cpp *******/
#define MYDEF
#include "mylib.h"
#include "module.h"

void main()
{
    foo foo_;
    module mod_;

    foo_.test();
    mod_.test();
}
```

Using `g++`, I compile each implementation file independently:
`module.cpp` --> `module.o`
`main.cpp` --> `main.o`

Then I proceed to link them together, creating the `a.out` executable:
`module.o` + `main.o` = `a.out`

All the above works out just fine, and executing `a.out` prints out:
ZERO
ZERO

Questions:
Considering that `module.o` and `main.o` must have a different definition of `foo::test()` due to `main.cpp` defining `MYDEF` and `module.cpp` not defining `MYDEF`, the linker must then choose one of the two definitions to keep because, as we see above, all calls to `foo::test()` express the same behaviour. How does the linker decide which `foo::test()` definition to use? Can I influence this decision? What if my library has a dozen more functions all depending on the `MYDEF` macro, is it a guarantee that all these functions will see the same `MYDEF` macro definition status? Making use of such behaviour breaks the one definition rule, but how else should one go about implementing for example conditionally compiled debug prints in `foo::test()` in a better way?

Comment: A tool like [ORC](https://github.com/adobe/orc) can detect ODR violations.  The upshot is:  all your source should have `MYDEF` defined, or none of your source should have `MYDEF` defined.  Mix-and-match isn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to influence this reliably.

Having two translation units compiled with `MYDEF` set differently is a ODR violation, because your program then contains two definitions for the class `foo` which are not identical. The program then is IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required) and effectively has undefined behavior.

This is not only a theoretical concern either. The compiler may arbitrarily inline calls to the `test` function or compile other functions under the assumption that `test` has the same behavior as visible to it in the translation unit.

So even if you could influence the linker to choose one of the two implementations, the program may still not behave as you would expect.

---

You get the conditional behavior reliably by either always recompiling the whole program with the new macro setting if you change it or by not using a header-only library for it. Instead put the conditional code in a single `.cpp` containing the definition of the method.